# HttpRequestException is not caught in catch block, xamarin.android , while same code works in UnitTest application

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin android project in which I'm calling API from PCL project, so when I call that API without internet connection, it throws HTTPRequestException, so I wrapped the code in try/catch block but the exception is still not caught..

I've run that code in UnitTest application and it works as expected, so I assume the problem is within xamarin.android and its multi-threading, so I wonder if there's any workaround

```
        public override async void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            try
            {

                progressBar.IsBusy = true;
                progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                progressBar.Title = "Loading...";




                var items = await ApiClient.Instance.GetAllAsync(); //this is supposed to throw httprequestexception when there is no internet connection.

                layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Activity, 3, GridLayoutManager.Vertical, false);

                onScrollListener = new CoinRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.AddOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);

                onScrollListener.LoadMoreEvent += OnScrollListener_LoadMoreEvent;
                SetAdapterWithAnim(recyclerView);
                progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException) //the exception is not caught
            {

                //some handling
            }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting a different exception than you expect?  Catch all exceptions, and see if something shows up.  You can switch back to "properly just catching your expected exceptions" afterwards.

Comment: @JRE I have put Exception instead of HttpRequestException, still same results.

Comment: OK.  Just checking.

Comment: If you're still unable to catch the exception using `catch(Exception) { ... }` then it's not being thrown in that block of code. Perhaps `base.OnActivityCreated` is throwing it instead? Or maybe you rethrow the exception in the catch block? Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: ```  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal C#
  0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException C#
  0x20 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8 C#
  0x12 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw C#
  0x6 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 C#
  0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. C#
  0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run C#
  0xA in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run C#
  0x11 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8 C#
``` @wlyles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the second fragment which was implemented into viewpager, I've forgot to wrap try/catch around it.